# Is there a decent algorithm for finding the shortest spanning walk in a weighted directed graph?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, directed-graph, weighted-graph

I have a weighted directed graph. I'm defining a "spanning walk" here as a walk through the graph that visits each vertex *at least* once, with no limitations on what edges need to be traversed. I'm trying to find the shortest of such walks, if one exists.
[Here's an image of an example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZJ62.png), whose shortest spanning walk is c->d->b->a, with a length of 6

I tried looking into Hamiltonian paths and the Traveling Salesman Problem and such, but as I'm allowed to visit a vertex multiple times in my problem, I don't know if I can make much use of it. I'm almost completely convinced the problem is NP-hard, but wondering if there's anything to make a search not take centuries for larger graphs.

Comment: This looks like a version of the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Comment: the TSP states you can visit each city only exactly once, which isn't a restriction here, but I'm sure it's very related, making an edit, thanks c: